# How to define order in which components are added to DataItem

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I've read a [tutorial](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/dataview) about creating `DataView` with custom comonent for each element from Store. It says about mapping fields of record to components in `DataItem`, but my question is how to define order in which components will be added to `DataItem`.

For example, I have such DataItem:

```
Ext.define('demo.view.CottageItem', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.component.DataItem',
    requires: ['Ext.Label', 'Ext.Array', 'Ext.Img'],
    xtype: 'listitem',

    config: {
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            align: 'center',
            pack: 'start',
        },
        title: {
            flex: 1
        },
        photo: {
            width: '140px',
            height: '140px'
        },

        dataMap: {
            getTitle: {
                setHtml: 'title'
            },
            getPhoto: {
                setSrc: 'photo'
            }
        },
        styleHtmlContent: true
    },

    applyTitle: function(config) {
        return Ext.factory(config, Ext.Label, this.getTitle());
    },

    updateTitle: function(newTitle, oldTitle) {
        if (oldTitle) {
            this.remove(oldTitle);
        }

        if (newTitle) {
            this.add(newTitle);
        }
    },

    applyPhoto: function(config) {
        return Ext.factory(config, Ext.Img, this.getPhoto());
    },

    updatePhoto: function(newImage, oldImage) {
        if (oldImage) {
            this.remove(oldImage);
        }

        if (newImage) {
            this.add(newImage);
        }
    },
});
```

It has layout type `hbox`, so I want photo to be added first and then title. So that title would be to the right of the photo. How can I achieve this?

Another question is, is there a way to add another container inside this `DataItem`, in which can be inserted my Label and Image?

**UPDATE:**
Now my layout looks like this:

|Label(title)|                     |Image(Photo)|

I want it look like this:

|Image(photo)| |Label(title)|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I understood how to solve my problem, here is my code:

```
Ext.define('demo.view.CottageItem', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.component.DataItem',
    requires: ['Ext.Label', 'Ext.Array', 'Ext.Img'],
    xtype: 'listitem',

    config: {
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            align: 'center',
            pack: 'start',
        },
        title: {
            style: {
                'font-weight': 'bold'
            }
        },
        photo: {
            width: '140px',
            height: '140px'
        },
        desc: {},

        dataMap: {
            getTitle: {
                setHtml: 'title'
            },
            getPhoto: {
                setSrc: 'photo'
            },
            getDesc: {
                setHtml: 'desc'
            },
        },
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                itemId: 'photoContainer',
            },
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox'
                },
                itemId: 'textContainer',
                flex: 1,
            }
        ],
    },

    applyTitle: function(config) {
        return Ext.factory(config, Ext.Label, this.getTitle());
    },

    updateTitle: function(newTitle, oldTitle) {
        if (oldTitle) {
            this.getComponent('textContainer').remove(oldTitle);
        }

        if (newTitle) {
            this.getComponent('textContainer').add(newTitle);
        }
    },

    applyPhoto: function(config) {
        return Ext.factory(config, Ext.Img, this.getPhoto());
    },

    updatePhoto: function(newImage, oldImage) {
        if (oldImage) {
            this.getComponent('photoContainer').remove(oldImage);
        }

        if (newImage) {
            this.getComponent('photoContainer').add(newImage);
        }
    },

    applyDesc: function(config) {
        return Ext.factory(config, Ext.Label, this.getDesc());
    },

    updateDesc: function(newDesc, oldDesc) {
        if (oldDesc) {
            this.getComponent('textContainer').remove(oldDesc);
        }

        if (newDesc) {
            this.getComponent('textContainer').add(newDesc);
        }
    },
});
```

Instead of adding components to root, I defined two panels (placeholders) inside `DataItem`. I access them using `getComponent` method and add my component to desired place. The only problem here is that order of items added to `textContainer` is undefined, but in my case I got desired order.

Answer (score 0):

Change sort order of the backend store? I'm not sure about component based DataView, but element-based matches to store sorting.

To properly set (or change) sorting you have to read Store's [config sorters](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-sorters) property or [sort](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-sort) function

Cheers, Oleg

Comment: no, not order of items in store, but order in which view components are added to DataItem. I updated my question

Comment: yes, that is exactly want I mean. If you change sorting in the store => you get changed layout on UI. Ever you do it at runtime, after creating the dataview. Have you checked? for element-based dataview it works 100%

Comment: I am talking about order of components in a single `DataItem`, not whole DataView. And just to be sure I had tried to change order of records inside store and layout of single DataItem didn't change.